# UPDATE SELECT Access

Tags: ms-access, select, sql-update

This is an MS Access 2010 related question.

Is it possible to go the short route (A) and write an UPDATE statement using a SELECT statement in order to catch the relevant value or do I have to go the long route (B) and I will firstly need to query the data through a SELECT statement that I will save as a query and then refer to this saved query in my UPDATE statement?

Here is (A):

```
UPDATE tbl_A
SET tbl_A.Header1 = (SELECT F1 FROM tblStaging
WHERE tblStaging.F1 = 'ISSUER CODE')
WHERE (((tbl_A.TableName)='tblStaging'));
```

Here is B:

```
SELECT F1
FROM tblStaging
WHERE F1 = 'ISSUER CODE';

UPDATE tbl_A, Q_A_Sel_ISSUERCODE
SET tbl_A.Header1 = [Q_A_Sel_ISSUERCODE].[F1]
WHERE (((tbl_A.TableName)='tblStaging'));
```

Thank you

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Chris gave the solution:

```
UPDATE tbl_A, tblStaging
SET tbl_A.Header1 = tblStaging.F1
WHERE (((tblStaging.F1)='ISSUER CODE') AND ((tbl_A.TableName)='tblStaging'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure about Access, but in SQL Server you can use a single UPDATE statement like this (and I would've thought it should also work in Access):

```
UPDATE A
SET Header1 = S.F1
FROM tbl_A A, tblStaging S
WHERE S.F1 = 'ISSUER CODE' AND A.TableName ='tblStaging';
```

Although if that's exactly what you want to do, it's the same as:

```
UPDATE tbl_A SET Header1 = 'ISSUER CODE'
WHERE TableName = 'tblStaging';
```

Comment: @ Chris thanks It does work and the SELECT statement is actually not necessary.

Comment: @ProtoVB If this answer solved your problem then you should [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/238021) it. (You've asked >20 questions and have not accepted an answer yet.)